# Flutter Web (Firestore Error)- Expected a value of type 'JSObject<qc>', but got one of type 'NativeJavaScriptObject'

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I was trying out flutter cloud firestore in my web project.

I'm on master channel and i'm using the following version in pubspec.yaml file.

```
cloud_firestore: ^0.13.5
```

**Index.html file :**

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

  <script>
    // TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration.
    // See: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592
    var firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "--apiKey--",
      authDomain: "--authDomain--",
      databaseURL: "--databaseURL--",
      projectId: "--testapp--",
      storageBucket: "--test.appspot.com--",
      messagingSenderId: "--senderId--",
      appId: "--appId--"
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

In My List Screen, I'm fetching data like :

```
var reference = widget.firestore.collection('work');
    print("reference : ${reference}");
    try {
      QuerySnapshot snapshot = await reference.getDocuments();
      print("work snapshot : ${snapshot}");
    } catch (error) {
      print("work error : ${error}");
    }
```

But, I'm getting an error while trying to fetch data from cloud firestore in my flutter web project.

**Error :**

```
Expected a value of type 'JSObject<qc>', but got one of type 'NativeJavaScriptObject'
```

Can anyone please suggest a workaround solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is in the beta

Comment: are you getting this `print("reference : ${reference}");` printed?

Comment: Yes i am getting this printed.

Comment: According to https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-dart/issues/263#issuecomment-568989330 Its an error returned from the firebase api. Can you inspect the returned reference and does it contain some error message or code?

Comment: That is what i am not able to track.

Comment: seriously? no solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the error thrown is because you're trying to assign `QuerySnapshot` when `reference.getDocuments()` returns a different value type. To fetch the documents inside the Collection, the [get()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/get.html) method should be used.

```dart
CollectionReference reference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('work');

QuerySnapshot snapshot = await reference.get();
```